# How to integration Square SDK in Android

Tags: android, sdk, square

When I initialize the Square SDK on the fragment, it initializes but does not get a response on `onActivityResult`  nothing is triggered.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


CardEntry.handleActivityResult(data, result -> {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        CardDetails cardResult = result.getSuccessValue();
        Card card = cardResult.getCard();
        String nonce = cardResult.getNonce();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Payment Success",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else if (result.isCanceled()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Canceled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
});
```

}